# Vue.js component doesn't react on data updates

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Try to render a data into `<table></table>` and add a event handler to update the data. My initial data is array of arrays. And handler just update these arrays.
Table rendered, handler forks fine and updates arrays, but updates doesn't show on the `<table></table>`. Line `{{ grid[row][column] }}` doesn't show updated data. Where is my mistake?

```
Vue.component('grid-component', {
  template: `
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(row, rowIndex) in grid">
        <td v-for="(column, columnIndex) in row" @click="onClickHandler" v-bind:row="rowIndex" v-bind:column="columnIndex">
          {{ grid[row][column] }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  `,
  props: ['grid', 'onClickHandler']
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    grid: createGrid(columnsInGrid, rowsInGrid),
  },
  methods: {
    put(event) {
      const target = event.target;
      const column = target.getAttribute('column');
      const row = target.getAttribute('row');
      this.grid[row][column] = 1;
    }
  }
})
```

In index.html:

```
<div id="app">
    <div is="grid-component" v-bind:grid="grid" v-bind:on-click-handler="put"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you read: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats. There are certain caveats in array change detection that are almost certainly at play here.

Comment: Also, what version of Vue are you using?

Comment: @webnoob Aw, no, thanks! I create my component using this example https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Components-and-v-for. But how is it works here without `Vue.set()`?

Comment: @webnoob I use https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6

Comment: Sorry, there was another link for array detection: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection. Take a look at the suggestions there.

Comment: @webnoob got it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work by design of vue reactivity. Please read https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats. There is no technical way to detect changes like `grid[index]`.

Change squared braces the Vue setter like:

```
Vue.set(grid[row], column, 1)
```

Comment: That's what I had in mind but didn't have time to look into it more, was on the way out :)

Comment: @webnoob you help me very much with both links, thanks!